# Website content has long blocking and waiting times for some files

Tags: apache-2.2

I am developing a website and it's running on my local machine. The page loads some content quickly but then the waterfall diagram shows long blocking and wait times for the rest of the content (mostly small images)

The first 13 or so files are delivered in less than 0.5 seconds and the rest have increasing block times and take 2 to 5 seconds to deliver, despite being just as small as the fast files.

- There is no AJAX on this page.

[image: website waterfall diagram]

I am using Apache 2.2 and have 16 GB of RAM on my machine. Is anyone familiar with the pattern shown in the waterfall diagram?

Any idea why some of the content might be delivered so slowly? Apache or other system problems?

Let me know what info you need... just hoping this kind of problem is old hat to a few of the wise masters!

Comment: The delays are almost exactly 1s; there's more than coincidence there. Do you have anything like mod_security enabled? Or perhaps DNS lookups of some kind?

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for the reply! I do not have mod_security loaded. If it matters, I do have ssl_module loaded. In my Apache config if have Hostnamelookups off and changed %h to %a in the LogFormat.

Comment: Any anti-virus software with firewall features? What OS is this?

Comment: I have clamav with the php interface but it does not initiate with each apache instance. It's weird that the first several files load quickly but the later ones are delayed. No firewall features that I know of... unless they are baked into Ubuntu 11.04.

Comment: Just to be sure I removed clamav.so and all its settings from my php.ini and restarted apache2. Everything loaded fast as desired... at first. After a few reloads it was back to the strange behavior with 1s delays. So, I don't think it's clamav related.

Comment: Have a look at the interface with `tcpdump -i eth0 -n host $client_ip`. Are there failed tries to create a connection? If so there may be limiting rules in the firewall.

Comment: Hi, thanks but I don't see any failed tries. Does this look like it would be something to do with the network setup on the OS or Apache and its modules? One thing that seems odd is that when Apache is restarted, the performance is good for a few page loads.

Comment: I was just doing some more research. Could this have anything to do with the availability of file descriptors? Seems unlikely for a stock set up.

Comment: Is your apache prefork?

Comment: Yes, it uses the mpm_prefork module. Start Servers 5, MinSpareServers 5, MaxSpareServers 10, MaxClients 150, MaxRequestsPerChild 0. I also saved the page as HTML (so no PHP processing) and the results were still the same.

Comment: It may be premature but it seems like setting KeepAlive Off may have improved things a lot. Now I have to find out why this might have been the problem.

Comment: KeepAlive Off definitely fixes the problem. I'm not completely sure why the requests are blocked because my KeepAlive timeout is 10s. I read a post saying that having the wrong content length in the header will cause the connection to stay open while it waits for data that never comes [link](http://feeding.cloud.geek.nz/posts/blocked-queued-connections-keep-alive/) My content length is correct for my gzipped files so I'd still really like to understand what is happening with KeepAlive.

Comment: There's definitely an interplay between KeepAlive and the prefork module. It seems like the 1 second delay is apache starting more prefork child server processes. Not sure why it does this only when KeepAlive is on.

Answer (score 1):

OK, it turns out I didn't have the problem in Windows 7, so I figured it could be related to the browser. My Ubuntu Firefox has (about:config) network.http.max-connections = 32. Firefox would try to open 32 connections to my server. The 1s delays were Apache spawning new child processes. Once I limited the max-connections to the size of my idle Apache processes, the problem when away. I can't rely on people changing their browser, so as a fix, I set the Apache MinSpareServers to 32. Also, if the MaxClients is set too low and KeepAlive is on, Firefox will still try to make 32 parallel connections but will have to wait until the KeepAlive expires so that new Apache child processes can be spawned.